# android crashing on thread initialization

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to develop a simple application on android. Basically, when the button is pressed a class is instantiated, then the class's fireMe methode is called. Which starts a new thread and implements its run method. The problem is here, when i debug the code, at this step of execution, the eclipse shows the Class File Editor source not found .. error. 
Here are the relevant parts of the code.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText name_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText phone_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            ServerConnection sv =new ServerConnection(name_text.getText().toString(),phone_text.getText().toString());
            sv.fireMe();
        }
```

This is the function declared in ServerConnection.

```
   public void fireMe(){
            Thread thd =new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    runm();
                }
            });
            thd.start();
    }
```

I have been busy with this like 10 hours, if somebody can shed light upon this, i would be really appreciatefull. Thank you.

Here is the stack output.

I also tried to define the class ServerConnection in the same file with the activity instantiating it. But it didn't work either. I tried to start a thread in the onclick function and it gave me the same error. It seems I am having problems with starting threads.

```
Lund [Android Application]  
    DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
            PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 511    
            ServerConnection.fireMe() line: 143 
            LundMenuScreenActivity$1.onClick(View) line: 32 
            Button(View).performClick() line: 2485  
            View$PerformClick.run() line: 9080  
            ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
            ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
            Looper.loop() line: 123 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3687    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 867  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 625 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
        Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Comment: can put the stack trace here? And also code snippet of `runm()`?

Comment: Yes a stack trace is needed to help solve this issue.

Comment: Class FileEditor source not found..? Have you declared the class in Manifest file?

Comment: Should i declare non component classes in the manifest file. If so which tag should i use. It is not an Activity, Service, Receiver, or Provider.

Comment: runm() function doesnt have anything in it currently.